# Python replace and strip not working to remove carriage return and new line \r\n

Tags: python, replace, newline

First of all, I'm sorry I'm asking this question, because by the looks of things there are hundreds of posts about removing \n and the like from a variable, but nothing seems to work for me.

So I'm using an arduino to sample values from a sensor and sending them across serial to my python script and reading lines in using serial.readline(). The formatting comes in pretty weird and I get messages of the following format:

```
b'100\r\n'
b''
b''
b''
b'101\r\n'
b''
b''
b'102\r\n'
```

I'm removing the blank line with a if num statement. I'm not sure why I'm getting the b appened at the front, but I can remove that fine using replace, as well as the the apostrophies. However nothing, not replace nor strip gets rid of the \r\n. What am I doing wrong? Here's my code

```
 try:
    num=ser.readline()
    if num:
      print(num)
      num=str(num)
      num = num.replace('b','')
      num = num.replace("'",'')
      num = num.replace('\r\n','')
      num=num.strip('\n\r')
      num=int(num)
      print(num)
```

The output of this code is:

```
b'100\r\n'
100\r\n
b'101\r\n'
101\r\n
b'102\r\n
102\r\n
```

Some weird things to note when debugging the num variable does not seem to be created until I do

```
num=str(num)
```

Or at least it doesn't show up in my variables tab in spyder. Also I need this line because without it the replace throws a Type error saying "a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"

N.B. It's when I don't convert to string, that it throws the type error saying it shouldn't be a string!

Secondly using " " or ' ' to encapsulate the b works, only "'" works for the apstrophy as it assumes I'm trying to write a comment but neither "\r\n" nor '\r\n' works for \r\n.

All help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did the trick thank you!

Comment: you are welcome.I deleted the comment by mistake.

Comment: The leading b is not part of a string but a prefix for a byte literal. What follows is not a string but a byte literal

Comment: For people who missed what shivsn said, \\r\\n did the trick because \ is considered an escape character in python.

But also bruno is also correct you can just do int(num) and that works too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b'100\r\n'` is the internal representation of the (byte) string, and you don't need to do anything special to pass it to `int`:

```
>>> s = b'100\r\n'
>>> print(s)
b'100\r\n'
>>> int(s)
100
>>>
```